# Migrating a header-detail pair of tables on sql server

Tags: sql-server, output-clause

How would you migrate SOME records from a header-detail pair of tables (with IDENTITY ID's) to a new pair of tables in another DB?

For example, yo need to migrate record numbered 4,6,9 and 10 from the header table and all their details.

When you INSERT the header records on the new table, their ID's will be 1,2,3 and 4. When inserting the details, the child record from 4 will need to point to 1, 6 to 2 and so on.

Is there a way to use the OUTPUT clause to include a field that is not inserted in the table, as a way to pair "old" ID' to "new" ones?

Comment: You can do it with SSIS.   The dataflow for the child table would have a lookup to get the new parent id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `OUTPUT` clause of an `INSERT` statement will only allow you to select values that are actually inserted into the target table. You can work around this by using a `MERGE` instead, as the `OUTPUT` clause of a `MERGE` statement will allow you to select values from the source data as well. Here's an example:

```
declare @src table (id bigint, data char);
declare @dest table (id bigint identity(1,1), data char);
insert @src values (4, 'A'), (6, 'B'), (9, 'C'), (10, 'D');

insert @dest (data)
    output inserted.id, S.id -- ERROR
    select data from @src S;

merge @dest D
    using @src S on 1 = 0
    when not matched then
        insert (data) values (S.data)
        output inserted.id as [New ID], S.id as [Old ID]; -- LEGAL
```

Results of the `MERGE` statement:

```
New ID  Old ID
1       4
2       6
3       9
4       10
```